# Oracle SQL - map Table onto a "time raster"

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

First of all: Please excuse my bad english. Iam not a native english speaker. ;) i try to do my best.

i have a problem with sql under oracle11.

this is my table with data: (example)

```
  -------------------------------------------------------
  | company  |      datetime       |  user   | actions  |
  -------------------------------------------------------
  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:00:00 |  userA   |   32     |
  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:00:00 |  userB   |   12     |
  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:00:00 |  userC   |   45     |

  |  1001    | 2015-09-10 00:00:00 |  userA   |   64     |
  |  1001    | 2015-09-10 00:00:00 |  userB   |   35     |
  |  1001    | 2015-09-10 00:00:00 |  userC   |   78     |

  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:06:00 |  userA   |   63     |
  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:06:00 |  userC   |   24     |

  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:12:00 |  userA   |   13     |
  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:12:00 |  userB   |   33     |    
  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:12:00 |  userC   |   83     |

  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:18:00 |  userC   |   35     |
  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:18:00 |  userD   |   56     |
  -------------------------------------------------------
```

you see, there are different times with user and actions.

i want to make now a query, which is giving me a record for "every user AND time"... 
i want to map it more or less to a "timeraster".. build by the datetime column from this table. even for the user with no entry at the specific time..

i.E. for the company "1000"

```
  -------------------------------------------------------
  | company  |      datetime       |  user   | actions  |
  -------------------------------------------------------
  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:00:00 |  userA   |   32     |
  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:00:00 |  userB   |   12     |
  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:00:00 |  userC   |   45     |
  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:00:00 |  userD   |   0      |

  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:06:00 |  userA   |   63     |
  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:06:00 |  userB   |   0      |
  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:06:00 |  userC   |   24     |
  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:06:00 |  userD   |   0      |

  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:12:00 |  userA   |   0      |
  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:12:00 |  userB   |   0      |
  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:12:00 |  userC   |   83     |
  |  1000    | 2015-09-10 00:12:00 |  userD   |   0      |
  -------------------------------------------------------
```

the amount of users differs for companys... (mainly between 4 and 25)..

i tried it allready with pivot tables. but i think there should by an easier way
to achive this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Partitioned outer join](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=312) to the rescue!

```
with sample_data as (select 1000 company, to_date('10/09/2015 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') datetime, 'userA' usr, 32 actions from dual union all
                     select 1000 company, to_date('10/09/2015 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') datetime, 'userB' usr, 22 actions from dual union all
                     select 1000 company, to_date('10/09/2015 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') datetime, 'userC' usr, 45 actions from dual union all
                     select 1001 company, to_date('10/09/2015 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') datetime, 'userA' usr, 64 actions from dual union all
                     select 1001 company, to_date('10/09/2015 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') datetime, 'userB' usr, 35 actions from dual union all
                     select 1001 company, to_date('10/09/2015 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') datetime, 'userC' usr, 78 actions from dual union all
                     select 1000 company, to_date('10/09/2015 00:06:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') datetime, 'userA' usr, 63 actions from dual union all
                     select 1000 company, to_date('10/09/2015 00:06:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') datetime, 'userC' usr, 24 actions from dual union all
                     select 1000 company, to_date('10/09/2015 00:12:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') datetime, 'userA' usr, 13 actions from dual union all
                     select 1000 company, to_date('10/09/2015 00:12:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') datetime, 'userB' usr, 33 actions from dual union all
                     select 1000 company, to_date('10/09/2015 00:12:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') datetime, 'userC' usr, 83 actions from dual union all
                     select 1000 company, to_date('10/09/2015 00:18:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') datetime, 'userC' usr, 35 actions from dual union all
                     select 1000 company, to_date('10/09/2015 00:18:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') datetime, 'userD' usr, 56 actions from dual),
           dates as (select distinct company, datetime from sample_data)
select sd.company,
       dts.datetime,
       sd.usr,
       nvl(sd.actions, 0) actions
from   dates dts
       left outer join sample_data sd partition by (sd.usr, sd.company) on (dts.datetime = sd.datetime)
where  dts.company = sd.company
order by 1, 2, 3;

   COMPANY DATETIME              USR      ACTIONS
---------- --------------------- ----- ----------
      1000 10/09/2015 00:00:00   userA         32
      1000 10/09/2015 00:00:00   userB         22
      1000 10/09/2015 00:00:00   userC         45
      1000 10/09/2015 00:00:00   userD          0
      1000 10/09/2015 00:06:00   userA         63
      1000 10/09/2015 00:06:00   userB          0
      1000 10/09/2015 00:06:00   userC         24
      1000 10/09/2015 00:06:00   userD          0
      1000 10/09/2015 00:12:00   userA         13
      1000 10/09/2015 00:12:00   userB         33
      1000 10/09/2015 00:12:00   userC         83
      1000 10/09/2015 00:12:00   userD          0
      1000 10/09/2015 00:18:00   userA          0
      1000 10/09/2015 00:18:00   userB          0
      1000 10/09/2015 00:18:00   userC         35
      1000 10/09/2015 00:18:00   userD         56
      1001 10/09/2015 00:00:00   userA         64
      1001 10/09/2015 00:00:00   userB         35
      1001 10/09/2015 00:00:00   userC         78
```