# How to group a table by months and group again by another column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My goal is to show every count of contract_signed per product_type arranged by months. I've already grouped the table into months but I've wanted to group it another time using the PRODUCT_TYPE column. The code below executes without error but doesn't output what I needed.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(a.dtime_signature, 'yyyy-mm') AS months,
A.PRODUCT_TYPE,
COUNT(A.CONTRACT_NUMBER) AS CONTRACT_SIGNED
FROM dm_sales.v_sales_dm_data a
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND a.contract_state <> 'Cancelled'
  AND a.cnt_signed = 1
  AND a.loan_type = 'Consumer Loan'
  AND A.DTIME_SIGNATURE >= DATE '2019-01-01'         
GROUP BY TO_CHAR (A.DTIME_SIGNATURE, 'yyyy-mm'), A.PRODUCT_TYPE
ORDER BY months asc
;
```

This is the result of the code:
[image: query_result]

The results are almost correct but the there are 62 product types. So It should be 62 product type results per month.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a table that stores all your product types? Normally you should have it, and in this case just join it with your query. (`product_types left join (select...) on ...`

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov the product_types can also be seen on the same table

Comment: If for any given month there's no data for some product_type, then you will not get a row for that combination.

Comment: @Ragirate in order to do this, you need to have a list of the product types you want to show for each month. That's why Sayan asked if you had a table that had that information present, otherwise you're going to have to make up something that generates that list, because as gsalem points out, if you haven't got a product type in a particular month, it won't be reported out (because you haven't told the database that you need to know about it).

Comment: Think about it like this: if I have a pool of differently coloured balls, that I have split into separate buckets, and I ask you to give me a count of the colours per bucket, you're just going to list the colours found in each bucket as you find them. If I tell you the list of colours the balls could be, then you can output the counts per bucket against that list of colours.

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871036/oracle-sql-map-table-onto-a-time-raster/32871369#32871369. Whilst you can create your list of product_types using a subquery that does a distinct product_type across the whole table, similar to the answer in the duplicate question, it's better if you have a table that already holds that information - what if a new product_type is introduced, but there are no sales on it yet? Plus you're doing a query on a table that is potentially very big and likely to get bigger, so performance degrades over time.